# AZURE ACS associating identities with multiple logins

Tags: session, azure, identity, acs

I am creating a webpage using Azure ACS, or "Windows Azure Active Directory Access Control" as it's also called.

I have managed to get this to work, and upon login I extract the claim information like this:

```
var identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as     Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
```

I then store the nameidentifier in a database so I can recognize the user when he logs in again.

Now I want to let the user log in using another identity while he is still logged in with the first one so that I may associate these two claim sets to the one user.

When I direct him to the acs loginpage and he is redirected back after logging in the list of claims in the identity is still the same, it doesn't contain new claims for the new identity he logged in with. Do I have to somehow store an identity in a cookie and log him off before redirecting him to the ACS login page to get the next identity claim information? If not how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement something like a verification code that will allow you to identify the user and store its various name identifiers.

1. user logs in
2. is it a "verified" user, i.e., its name
   identifier is associated with a user? 
   2a. Yes, proceed. 
   2b. No, ask
   for the verification code 
   2b1. Valid code, associate user with
   verification code 
   2b2. Invalid code, go to 2b

This way multiple identities can be associated with the same user through the verification code.

Hope this helps!